# setAndroidContext in Kotlin (Firebase)

Tags: java, database, firebase, kotlin

Using Firebase Database, how would I setAndroidContext in Kotlin?

This is it in Java:

```
public class SimpleDatabase extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
}}
```

Comment: That API is for a **very** old version of the Firebase SDK that's no longer supported.  I suggest upgrading. There is no need to do anything like this in recent versions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start

Comment: Sorry, I'm just watching tutorials on YouTube...